# Wordpress PHP Cookie Not Updating and Redirecting to Correct Location

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, cookies

I am storing cookies when a certain page has been accessed. The cookie is being stored when accessing city1, and even appears updated in Developer Tools when city2 is accessed... but despite my efforts, the value from city one continues to be the redirect location.

I just want the redirect location to change if city2 is accessed, but it keeps going to "Google.ca" despite the value being updated to "Bing.ca" when visiting my homepage.

Whats going on here?

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'location_cookie' );
    function location_cookie() {
// get postname (I used postname in 'Permalink Settings')
$location = get_query_var('name');

// if user is on startpage + was not redirected yet -> redirect
// if you don't set the userRedirected cookie, the user is not 
// able to visit the startpage anymore to chose a location
if($location == "" && isset($_COOKIE["location"]) /*&& !$_COOKIE["userRedirected"]*/)
{
    // path "/" makes the cookie available on the whole domain
    /*setcookie("userRedirected", true, null, "/");*/ // duration: session
    header("location: ".$_COOKIE["location"]); // redirect
}

if($location == "city1")
{
    // set location cookie 1
    setcookie("location", "google.ca", time() + 2592000, "/");
}
elseif($location == "city2")
{
    // set location cookie 2
    setcookie("location", "bing.ca", time() + 2592000, "/");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have updated the cookie by passing 'name=city2' get variable ?

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'location_cookie' );


function location_cookie()
{
    // get postname (I used postname in 'Permalink Settings')
    $location = get_query_var('name');

    // if user is on startpage + was not redirected yet -> redirect
    // if you don't set the userRedirected cookie, the user is not
    // able to visit the startpage anymore to chose a location
    if(empty($location) && isset($_COOKIE["location"])){
        // path "/" makes the cookie available on the whole domain
        /*setcookie("userRedirected", true, null, "/");*/ // duration: session
        header("location: ".$_COOKIE["location"]); // redirect
    }

    if($location == "city1"){
        // set location cookie 1
        setcookie("location", "google.ca", time() + 2592000, "/");
        echo $location;
    }
    elseif($location == "city2"){
        // set location cookie 2
        setcookie("location", "bing.ca", time() + 2592000, "/");
        echo $location;
    }
}
```

Try to set city1 and city2 and make sure you are seeing the value in the dom.